# Fastboot: Lock state - Locked on nexus 7

Tags: nexus-7, bootloader, fastboot

I am having trouble unlocking the bootloader on my Nexus 7. When I boot into fastboot I see the message LOCK STATE - LOCKED. I want to unlock the bootloader so I can re-install the stock operating system since the device hangs on the "Google" logo screen.

I can see the device with the 'fastboot devices' command in command prompt but when I type in 'fastboot oem unlock' and accept the command on the android device I get an error:

```
C:\Android\platform-tools>fastboot oem unlock
...
(bootloader) erasing userdata...
(bootloader) erasing userdata done
(bootloader) erasing cache...
(bootloader) erasing cache done
(bootloader) unlocking...
FAILED (remote: (Unknown error code))
finished. total time: 1.614s
```

Is the device broken or is there a solution? Booting into recovery mode and trying to restore the device just makes it hang forever.

Comment: You don't need to unlock the bootloader to flash a stock ROM signed by the manufacturer.

Comment: I downloaded the image from here: https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#nakasi. If I use the flash-all batch file it gives me "Bootloader is locked" error and if I try "fastboot flash recovery recovery.img" it also gives me "Bootloader is locked".

Comment: hey, see this http://www.technorms.com/27360/how-to-lock-unlock-nexus-7-bootloader